# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytop'

Tags: python, algorithm, import, modulenotfounderror

I have installed pyotp but still I am getting below error

C:\Users\PANKAJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe C:\Users\PANKAJ\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\L1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\PANKAJ\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\L1.py", line 1, in 
import pytop
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytop'

My code is

```
import pytop
from NorenRestApiPy.NorenApi import  NorenApi

class ShoonyaApiPy(NorenApi):
    def __init__(self):
        NorenApi.__init__(self, host='https://api.shoonya.com/NorenWClientTP/', websocket='wss://api.shoonya.com/NorenWSTP/')
        global api
        api = self

import logging
import pyotp

#enable dbug to see request and responsesŚŚŚḌŚŚŚ
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

#start of our program
api = ShoonyaApiPy()

#credentials
token = 'XX'
otp = pyotp.TOTP(token).now()

user        = 'XX'
u_pwd       = 'Purav@84'
factor2     = otp
vc          = 'XX_U'
app_key     = 'XX'
imei        = 'test12345'

ret = api.login(userid=user, password=u_pwd, twoFA=otp, vendor_code=vc, api_secret=app_key, imei=imei)
print(ret)

#
```

What can be solution for this?

Comment: Can you try running `pip freeze` from your cmd, to know if its actually installed?

Answer (score 0):

[`pyotp`](https://pypi.org/project/pyotp/) is a third party package not included in the Python standard library. Have you installed it by running `pip install pyotp`?